# VIM: Shortcut to insert empty liquid tags?

Tags: vim, tags, jekyll, liquid

I'm migrating my blog to [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) and using MacVim to write my posts. I notice that I'm writing tags that look like this a lot:

```
{% highlight bash %}
chmod -R g+w test
{% endhighlight %}
```

or even...

```
{{ content }}
```

Is there a shortcut to insert the `{{ }}` or `{% %}` tags?

Note: I'm fairly new to Vim so any help is appreciated. I have Tim Pope's [Liquid plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-liquid) installed as well as the surround plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [ragtag](https://github.com/tpope/vim-ragtag) by Tim Pope. It provides mappings like `<c-x>=` for `{{ foo }}` and `<c-x>-` for `{% foo %}`.

If you do not want ragtag and since you have surround installed you may want to create your own mappings. I suggest you create a `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/liquid.vim` and put in the following:

```
let b:surround_45 = "{% \r %}"
let b:surround_61 = "{{ \r }}"
```

This will create surround mappings for `<c-s>=` and `<c-s>-` just like ragtag.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check out ragtag. I know that I somehow already have similar mappings setup for erb files, but it doesn't look like I have ragtag installed already.

Comment: Ragtag is a bunch of win. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use keyboard maps, like

```
:imap I{ {{}}<esc>hhi
```

With it if you type <kbd>I{</kbd> in insert mode it will insert `{{}}` then switches back to normal mode moves the cursor back to the 1st `}` then goes to insert mode back.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping to find something a little more robust though.